# Use data from angular to make external api call in node express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to use data that the user inputs to make an api call to an external API using node. I have successfully made calls from the server, and returned them to angular. But I need to send the server a variable from angular, have it make a call, and return the response to my view. I am new to node so I am sorry if this has already been answered somewhere. I looked around and found nothing.

**My html**

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Player 1</label>
    <input ng-model="player1.username">
</md-input-container>
<md-button ng-click="comparePlayers(player1, player2)">COMPARE!</md-button>
```

**My controller function**

```
$scope.comparePlayers = function(player1) {
    Nerd.getPlayer(player1)
}
```

**My 'Nerd' Service**

```
smiteStats.factory('Nerd', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
            getPlayer: function(playerName) {
            $http.post('/api/getPlayer', playerName).success(function(data) {
                console.log("sent to server"); //does not run
            })
        }
}]);
```

**My Express Route**

```
app.post('/api/getPlayer', GetPlayer.apiGetPlayer);
```

**My node module that makes the api call**

```
module.exports = {
    apiGetPlayer: function(error, res, player) {
        console.log(player); //this returns "[Function: next_layer] in my cmd
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send Parameters with $http in POST:

```
$http({
    url: host + '/api/getPlayer',
    method: "POST",
    data: { 'fruit1' : "Apple"}
})
.then(function(response) {
        // success
}, 
function(response) { // optional
        // failed
});
```

To get POST parameters, you will need the ExpressJS [body-parser](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters#post-parameters) package. This will allow you to grab information from the POST.

[Read more](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters#post-parameters)

Comment: This worked, I can now console log it from my route.js on the server, but how can I pass req.body into the node module?